# How do I make sure a function is called inside a parent component, from a child component that updates state in React Native?

Tags: react-native, async-await, parent-child, react-functional-component

I have been trying, and failing to add onboarding to my React Native application. I know I should have used Navigation and React-Native-Onboarding-Swiper or similar, but before this it is only a single page application so was trying to avoid it.

Anyway, I have a piece of state called onboarded, that is used to check if the onboarding has been completed previously and if it has the onboardingScreen component doesn't get called and instead it should just load the app.

I have tried to use AsyncStorage to store the onboarded state, but seem to be be hitting a snag as the function I am calling from the onboardingScreen to set this state and store it doesn't seem to be being called correctly. It also has an unhandled promise rejection that I need to work out how to solve, but that can come later.

I am passing three props to the OnboardingScreen component: images - which is the images to be displayed on each screen; setOnboardingComplete - function used to call the saving of the piece of state in AsyncStorage; and onboarded - the state that needs updating so I could check what it's current state was.

Here is the code from my App.js file (minus the irrelevant parts) ...

```
import {React, useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import RNBootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// Other Imports

import SplashScreen from './Splashscreen';
import OnboardingScreen from './OnboadingScreen.js';
import {
  Animated,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

function App() {
  const [onboarded, setOnboarded] = useState();

  const onboardingImages = [
    {
      id: 1,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen1v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen2v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen3.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen4v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen5v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen6v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen7v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen8v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen9v2.png'),
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      source: require('./assets/onboarding-images/OnboardingScreen10v2.png'),
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      // …do multiple sync or async tasks
      getStorage();
      console.log('AsyncStorage has been read.');
    };

    init().finally(async () => {
      await RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true, duration: 500});
      console.log('Bootsplash has been hidden successfully');
    });
  }, []);

  if (!onboarded) {
    return (
      <OnboardingScreen
        images={onboardingImages}
        setOnboardingComplete={onPressFinish}
        onboarded={onboarded}
      />
    );
  }


  const getStorage = async () => {
    const onboarded = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ONBOARDED');
    setOnboarded(JSON.parse(onboarded));
  };

  const onPressFinish = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      'ONBOARDED',
      JSON.stringify({
        Onboarded: true,
      }),
    );

    console.log('Onboarded Set To TRUE!! :)');
  };

  return ( ...



export default App;
```

and this is the OnboardingScreen.js component minus the styling ...

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const OnboardingScreen = ({images, setOnboardingComplete, onboarded}) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (currentIndex === images.length - 1) {
      // Call setOnboardingComplete when last image is displayed
      setOnboardingComplete;
      console.log('onboardingComplete called from OnboardingScreen.js');
      console.log(onboarded);
    } else {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);

      console.log(onboarded);
    }
  };

  const handleSkip = () => {
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
      // Call setOnboardingComplete when skip button is clicked
      setOnboardingComplete;
    } else {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#13284d" />
      <View style={styles.carouselContainer}>
        <Image
          source={images[currentIndex].source}
          style={styles.carouselImage}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleSkip}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            {currentIndex === 0 ? 'Skip' : 'Back'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleNext}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            {currentIndex === images.length - 1 ? 'Done' : 'Next'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default OnboardingScreen;
```

So my actual problem is when I click the skip or back button on the OnboardingScreen the onPressFinish function isn't being called at all. Nothing is printed in the console so for some reason it just isn't working and I can't work out what I have done wrong.

If anyone has any insight what so ever, I will be eternally grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm a little bit confused. what is your actual problem?

Comment: Would have helped if I had been a little clearer, sorry. My problem is when I click the skip or back button on the OnboardingScreen the onPressFinish function isn't being called at all.

Comment: Is that because you just call it as a variable? try changing `setOnboardingComplete` to `setOnboardingComplete()`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This throughs an error in the console...   ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes

Comment: What if you move `const onPressFinish = async () => {...` to be above where you call `OnboardingScreen` in the App.jsx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that hasn't made any difference either. :(